# two select at a time in combo box - how to solve it?

Tags: php, html, mysql, xhtml

Here I'm using combo box for searching  working fine fetch from MySQL.

here is the code

```
<select name="location" class="styled">
    <option selected="selected" value=''>Any</option>
    <?php
    while ($loc_row = mysql_fetch_array($loc_result))
    {
     echo "<option value='$loc_row[job_location]'";
     if($loc_row['job_location'] == $location)
      {
        echo 'selected="selected"'; 
      }
      echo ">$loc_row[job_location] </option>";
    }
    ?>
    </select>
```

when click on search get string becoming as selected `$location=isset($_GET['location'])?$_GET['location']:'';` during this time there are two selected value.

could any one can help me to be one select value please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `selected="selected"` from the default "Any" option. The first element is selected by default.

Comment: exactly that is right :)
I just missed to think that way 
Any way thank bro